# When kernel space is used up, will OOM killer be triggered?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory, out-of-memory

We know if a user space program keeps malloc(), it may finally trigger OOM killer. But what about kernel space, when kernel space memory is used up, will it trigger OOM killer to free memory?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There’s an important distinction between kernel allocations and user-space allocations on Linux by default (which applies whenever the OOM killer is a factor). The kernel memory allocation functions allocate address space *and* physical pages, so that when the allocation function returns, the caller knows that any valid pointer returned is immediately usable. From user space, memory allocation allocates address space, and by default only allocates pages when necessary (and that’s when the OOM killer comes into play).

Put another way, kernel memory allocations never allow overcommitting.

A kernel memory allocation can end up triggering the OOM killer, to free up pages allocated to user space. There are a number of conditions on this, since such allocations may be made in contexts where I/O isn’t possible, or the file system can’t be re-entered, etc. See [the GFP flag documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/mm-api.html#mm-api-gfp-flags) for details. There are other reclaim mechanisms available for kernel allocations, used for caches etc.; when the kernel runs out of memory, it can flush those (in some circumstances) to recover some.

Comment: So when kernel memory is run out, it will trigger the OOM killer to free up memory of user space process. If kernel keeps kmalloc to run out of all the memory of the machine, what will happen?

Comment: I just tried. It still trigges OOM killer. Even if I disable OOM killer according to https://serverfault.com/questions/141988/avoid-linux-out-of-memory-application-teardown, OOM killer is still triggered

Comment: Yes, the kernel will run its own reclaim, and if necessary (and possible), it will trigger the OOM killer. If it still can’t free memory, it will presumably end up panicking.